# AppEngine - Setting different properties for different versions

Tags: google-app-engine

I have some Google AppEngine application deployed and I've set multiple version for testing (let's say stating and live). How can I write a single properties file with different settings depending on version?

I forgot to add: I use xml and java

Answer (score 1):

You could use environment variables in your yaml files. That way you can have different settings for each version of your app. e.g:

App Version 'staging'

```
application: myapp
version: staging
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true    
env_variables:
  setting_1: 1
  setting_2: "in staging"
```

App Version 'live'

```
application: myapp
version: live
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true    
env_variables:
  setting_1: 999
  setting_2: "running live"
```

You can then access them from within your app:

```
import os
print os.environ['setting_1']
```

See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Defining_environment_variables

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach

I use a custom yaml file., with testing, prod sections.
You can then name you version with trailing suffix -prod, -test etc.

Then based on the version suffix read use the appropriate section of the yaml file.

Comment: I much prefer the other answer ;-) I had forgotten the introduction of env variables in app.yaml